# Proving that an algorithm is correct using a loop invariant

Tags: algorithm

From *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen et al. (3rd ed.), I am doing exercise 2.1-3. Basically, given an vector `A` of length `n` and a value `v`, the algorithm outputs an index `i` (indices start at `1`, rather than `0`) such that `v = A[i]`, or `NIL` if such an index does not exist.

My pseudocode is the following:

```
for j = 1 to length(A):
    value = A[j]
    if v == value:
        return j
return 'NIL'
```

How do I use a loop invariant to prove that this is correct? I'm not sure how to extend their discussion of the loop invariant on the insertion-sort algorithm to this algorithm here (known as the linear-search algorithm).

I suppose, when `j = 1`, you have a (sub-)vector of length `1`, which has a component that is trivially either `v` or not `v`.

When you have a sub-vector of length `j = k`, if we assume that the algorithm works, then for `j = k+1`, it is trivial (I think?).

I'm clearly not understanding this method of proving that an algorithm is correct, although I *am* very familiar with mathematical induction, but I have no idea how to pursue this problem.

Comment: OP: would a property like "while I'm in the loop, any element preceding `A[j]` was not equal to `v`" help you in your proof?

Comment: Is there any formalislm like [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) used in the assigment?

Comment: The invariant I would use here is "At the top of the loop, we know that none of A[1], ..., A[j-1] are equal to v."  This is trivially true when j=1, and it's also easy to show the inductive case (assume it holds for j=k, then use this to show that it holds for j=k+1).  If we get to `return 'NIL'` then it must be that in the previous moment we were at the top of the loop with j=length(A)+1, which together with the invariant implies that v is not in A.

Comment: That shows that if the algorithm returns NIL then it is correct in doing so.  You also need to prove that if it returns some non-NIL value then it's also a correct answer (this is easy, since only one `return` statement could be used to produce such a return value, and the immediately preceding `if` guarantees it).  To be thorough you would also need to show that it terminates (though that's obvious here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop invariant is: `A[i] != v` for all `1 <= i < j`

The loop invariant is always maintained at each iteration. Assume otherwise that there exists an `i < j` such that `A[i] = v`. The algorithm would return `i` before reaching the `j`th-iteration.

The loop invariant helps prove the correctness, because upon termination there are two possible cases. Either (1) `j <= length(A)`, where the loop invariant and the if-statement suggest that `A[j] = v` and the algorithm correctly returns `j`; or (2) `j > length(A)`, where the loop invariant implies that for all `i <= length(A)`, `A[i] != v`, in which case the algorithm correctly returns `NIL`.